# Перевод текстовых числительных в натуральную форму

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть задача: На вход подается фраза на русском языке, содержащая числительное. Например, "Я хочу квартиру за 10.5 миллионов" или "Мне нравится когда моя машина, стоимостью сотку штук баксов, мелькает по телевизору". Необходимо выделить числительное в форме натурального числа и вернуть.

Пока что есть только идея создать словарь, где ключами будут словесные представления, а значениями натуральные числа, но учитывая, что могут встречаться жаргоны, разговорные формы и прочее словарь будет слишком большим.

Тестовое задание на junior программиста, так что возможно есть решение проще. 
Пожалуйста, помогите, поделитесь идеями решения.

Comment: Сторонними библиотеками можно пользоваться? Посмотрите библиотеку pymorphy2: https://pymorphy2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: И еще вопрос, что в этих предложениях является числительным? В первом предложении, например, числительное только 10.5.

Comment: Да, библиотеками пользоваться можно.

Comment: В первом предложении вывод должен быть 10 500 000, во втором - 100 000

Comment: Тогда [natasha](https://habr.com/ru/post/349864/) + свой парсер для числовых данных. Но нужно больше примеров что на вход подается, иначе слишком расплывчатое задание.

Comment: Не знаю, как по мне словарём не обойтись. Нужно писать лингвистическую нейросеть. Вот смотрите: есть у вас словарь, в котором есть такие ключ-значение: {"сотка":100, "сотку":100}. Логично. Теперь я пишу: "Дай мне сотку баксов". Понятно, что 100$. А теперь я скажу: "Дай мне сотку баксов, я куплю себе нормальную сотку". И что мы имеем: по словарю будет, что я 2 раза упоминаю 100$, а я хотел один раз употребить в значении 100$, а другой раз - в значении сотового телефона.